# Character replacement takes very much time in a string

Tags: java, binary

I am trying to replace a single character (bit) in a string, which is a binary number. For bit replacement i have designed a method, which simply partition the string using `string.substring()` method accoring to the given index then concatenates all. Below is the method-

```
    /*
     *Method will replace the index-th bit with bitToInsert in the given str
     */
    String str = "11000110100110011111"; 
    int index = 5;
    int bitToInsert = 0;
    if (index == 0) {
        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1) + bitToInsert;
    } else {
        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - index - 1) + bitToInsert + str.substring(str.length() - index);
    }
```

This works fine, however this takes very much time to replace a bit, when given str is very large. Is there any other way, so that replacement of any bit can be done in much less time compare to the above method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `StringBuffer` instead of `String` you can do this:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("11000110100110011111");
sb.setCharAt(index, '0');
```

Comment: If the string of bits will only be accessed by one thread, using a StringBuilder instead of a StringBuffer would be faster because it avoids unneeded synchonization.

Comment: Good hint. The OP shuold consider that.

Answer (score 4):

The performance problems you are seeing are because Java Strings are *immutable*.  In other words a String cannot be changed once it has been created.  So to change one character in the String the JVM has to make a copy of the whole String which will take a while if it is a big String.

In the above code it's actually even worse than that as you're making a copy of the first part of the string and the second part of the string apart from one character, and then having to copy these copies into the final result.  You could improve the performance if the above code by [using a `StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build the destination String so you only need to do the copy once.

If you really are dealing with a long binary number you should consider [using a `BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).  How well this will work for you will depend on what you're doing with the data once you've flipped some bits.

```
 String str = "11000110100110011111"; 
 BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(str.length());

 //All bits are unset at first so set any that correspond to a '1' in the String
 for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
   if (str.charAt(i) == '1') {
     bitSet.set(i);
   }
 }

 int index = 5;
 boolean bitToInsert = false; //i.e. 0
 bitSet.set(index, bitToInsert);
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about BitSet before.  One possible problem though is it's sort of a pain if the OP needs to convert it to and from a string representation repeatedly.

Comment: I agree.  Like I said in the answer how well `BitSet` will do here will depend on what is being done with the data.  If it needs to be output again as `String` immediately converting to a `BitSet` might be too much of an overhead, but if the code just needs to examine and alter the data a `BitSet` could be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Using BitSet and StringBuffer is a good idea. However, I have another suggestion **optimized for low memory and high speed**.
Use an int or long depending on how long your binary number is.
If it can't fit in a long use an array of ints/long whatever fits your needs better.

I will demonstrate here how you use an array of byte type to store 11000110100110011111:

```
 byte [] bits = new byte[1000];
 String str = "11000110100110011111";

 int arrayIndex=0; //position in array
 int bitIndex=0; //which bit at bits[arrayIndex] is it

 //put your bits into a byte array
 for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
     arrayIndex = i / 8;
     bitIndex = i % 8; //you can have max 8 bits in a byte

     bits[arrayIndex]=  (byte) (bits[arrayIndex] | ((Byte.parseByte(""+str.charAt(i)) << bitIndex)));
 }
```

This is how you change a specific bit:

```
 //for replacing bit bitNumber with bitValue (where bitValue is 0 or 1)
 void changeBit(int bitNumber, byte bitValue){
     int arrayIndex= bitNumber / 8;
     int bitIndex= bitNumber % 8;

     //clear bit first
     byte crtBit = (byte)(1 << bitIndex);
     crtBit = (byte) ~crtBit;
     bits[arrayIndex]= (byte) (bits[arrayIndex] & crtBit);
     //set bit to new value
     bits[arrayIndex]= (byte) (bits[arrayIndex] | (bitValue << bitIndex));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but I don't know if it will be any faster

```
String temp = "1111111111111";
char[] array = temp.toCharArray();
array[5] = '0';
temp = new String(array);
```